# ST_Distance_Spheroid does not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, spatial

I've try use MySql function `ST_Distance_Spheroid` for calculating distance but got following error :

> `ST_Distance_Spheroid` does not exist.

Is something missing?

Answer (score 2):

`ST_Distance_Sphere()` is special optimization on a sphere. If you want to calculate using an *spheroid* just use `ST_Distance().` From the [docs on `ST_Distance()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance)

> `ST_Distance()` detects arguments in a **geographic (ellipsoidal) spatial reference system and returns the geodetic distance on the ellipsoid.** The only permitted geographic argument types are `Point` and `Point`, or `Point` and `MultiPoint` (in any argument order). If called with other geometry type argument combinations in a geographic SRS, an `ER_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_GEOGRAPHIC_SRS` error occurs.

An ellipsoid is a spheroid where two axes have the same length.

Comment: Caveat:  The non-planer version of `ST_DISTANCE` is not available until MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

`ST_Distance_Sphere()` - in 5.7.6.  Do you have a link saying that "Spheroid" is available?